# Spring-samples don't understand the templates

Tags: spring, templates, maven-2, sample

Could please anybody explain to my how the templates work ? Can't find any info about it, there is no README, nothing. Is it supposed to be some kind of maven archetype or what ?

https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe these templates are for [SpringSource Tools Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts) (STS).

1. Go to **File > New > Spring Template Project**.
2. Select the template and click **Next**.
3. Enter the project name and top-level package name, then **Finish**.
4. Et voila.